# Whenever additional function is referenced the visualization fails to load

Tags: javascript, function, xmlhttprequest, google-visualization

Whenever rest(); function is referenced the visualization fails to load

```
canopy = rest("DIS");
```

The rest(); function pulls additional data from a google spreadsheet through XMLHttpRequest and makes it into an object. Then the stock symbol is used to reference the corresponding data. Outside the function the google.visualization.Query is pulling hierarchy data for the tree map

The map runs correctly when the function is not being referenced but when I uncomment 'canopy' it fails to load. When rest(); is run separately from the other code it works fine. I am not sure what is causing the failure to load.

link to jsfiddle  - -  https://jsfiddle.net/ax5daow1/

Thanks!

Comment: You've got some errors in the code, check your console _`ReferenceError: symbol1 is not defined`_ This is because `reqListener` is an _asynchronous_ callback and hasn't yet set `symbol1` when you're trying to `.replace` on it (line 13)

Comment: Looking further, you're also attempting to `return` from the `rest` function which will not work as you expect, **you're mixing _asynchronous_ and _synchronous_ code**.

Comment: pilot error - when in doubt, look in the debug log to see what errors your script is generating.  Then work on understanding and correcting those errors.